# KVO not called when merging changes from background context

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext, key-value-observing

I've subclassed `NSManagedObject` to add some properties that deal with ordering the object's relationship sets, this ordering is then stored in a property. I use KVO to determine when the original set changes and nil the stored property so that it orders using the updated set's data.

However the issue I'm having is that the changes to these sets are performed in a background context and then merged back into the main context which updates the `NSManagedObject` subclass but without firing the KVO observers that I've set up. Which in turns means that I don't nil the stored property.

How can I tell when an `NSManagedObject` subclass has been updated via a merge?

Below is my KVO structure inside the subclass:

```
#pragma mark - Awake

- (void)awakeFromFetch
{
    [super awakeFromFetch];

    /*-------------------------------*/

    [self addObserver:self
           forKeyPath:@"comments"
              options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
              context:NULL];

}

#pragma mark - KVO

- (void) observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                       ofObject:(id)object
                         change:(NSDictionary *)change
                        context:(void *)context
{

    if ([object isEqual:self])
    {
        if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"comments"])
        {
            _orderedComments = nil;
        }
    }

}

#pragma mark - OrderedComments

- (NSArray *)orderedComments
{
    if (!_orderedComments)
    {
        NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"dateCreated"
                                                                       ascending:NO];

        NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];

        _orderedComments = [self.comments sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    }

    return _orderedComments;
}
```

Additional information:

I'm using the parent-child pattern for controlling my `NSManagedObjectContexts` so when I create the main context:

```
_managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
```

and in each `NSOperation` context I create the child/background context:

```
    _localManagedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSConfinementConcurrencyType];
    [_localManagedObjectContext setParentContext:[CDSServiceManager managedObjectContext]];

    [_localManagedObjectContext setUndoManager:nil];
    [_localManagedObjectContext setMergePolicy:NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy];
```

(`CDSServiceManager` is a helper class to allow access to the main context)

I use the following to control merging:

```
- (void) saveLocalContextChangesToMainContextWithSuccess:(void (^)(void))success
                                                 failure:(void (^)(NSError *error))failure
{
    NSError *localManagedObjectContentSaveError = nil;

    if (![self.localManagedObjectContext save:&localManagedObjectContentSaveError])
    {
        DLog(@"Error to saving local context: %@", [localManagedObjectContentSaveError userInfo]);

        if (failure)
        {
            failure(localManagedObjectContentSaveError);
        }
    }
    else
    {

        [[CDSServiceManager managedObjectContext] performBlock:^
         {
             NSError *mergeSaveError = nil;

             if (![[CDSServiceManager managedObjectContext] save:&mergeSaveError])
             {
                 DLog(@"Error saving main context: %@", [mergeSaveError userInfo]);

                 if (failure)
                 {
                     failure(mergeSaveError);
                 }

             }
             else
             {

                 if (success)
                 {
                     success();
                 }

             }

         }];
    }
}
```

This is called from the `NSOperation` subclass.

Comment: How are these being merged?  How did you construct the background context?  Is it a parent child design?  Are you watching notifications?

Comment: @MarcusS.Zarra somehow I didn't see that you had commented, sorry about that. I've updated the question with additional information about how the NSManagedObjectContext's are created and merged.

Comment: As a minor point, when you are using KVO, you should not set the context to `NULL`.  You should set it to something testable and then if a KVO notification comes in that does not match your context you should pass it to `super`.  Foundation uses KVO as well.

Comment: Secondarily I would not check object against self.  I would be looking at the key path.  I would also put an NSLog at the top before any checks to see if the method is evening being called.  A breakpoint would work as well.